Не воспроизводится музыка SFML
Когда я запускаю игру, sf::Music не воспроизводится. Я закрываю окно и вижу в консоли вот это:
AL lib: (EE) ALCmmdevPlayback_mixerProc: Failed to get padding: 0x88890004
Failed to open sound file "Assets/Boiler.ogg" (couldn't open stream)
Error when opening music
Failed to play audio stream: sound parameters have not been initialized (call initialize() first)

main.cpp:
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    Game game;
    game.run();

    return 0;
}

Game.hpp:
class Game
{
public:

    Game();
    ~Game();

    void run();
    void update();
    void render();

private:

    //Variables

    sf::RenderWindow* window;
    sf::Event sfEvent;
    sf::Music music;

    //Initialization

    void init();

    void initWindow();
    void initMusic();    
};

Game.cpp:
Game::Game()
{
    init();
}

Game::~Game()
{
    this->music.stop();
    delete this->window;
}

void Game::run()
{
    this->music.play();

    while (this->window->isOpen())
    {
        this->update();
        this->render();
    }
}


void Game::init()
{
    this->initWindow();
    this->initMusic();
}

void Game::initWindow()
{
    this->window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "Arkanoid", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
    this->window->setFramerateLimit(60);
    this->window->setMouseCursorVisible(false);
}

void Game::initMusic()
{
    if (!this->music.openFromFile("Assets/Boiler.ogg"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error when opening music\n";
    }

    this->music.setLoop(true);
}


sfml-audio-d.lib и <SFML/Audio.hpp> тоже подключены.

Путь к файлу указывайте полный.

И снова на те же грабли, вам уже в прошлом вопросе говорилось о том что у вас не правильно указан относительный путь.

if (!this->music.openFromFile("C:/Users/Admin/source/repos/ArkanoidVtorushin/Assets/Boiler.ogg"))
{
std::cout << "Error when opening music\n";
}             -           сделал так, ничего не сработало

Что вы используете для сборки проекта? Visual studio, vscode, и.т.д.

¿Ошибка осталась та же или поменялась?

@evo - visual studio.

@user7860670 - осталась только первая строчка, то есть "Al Lib: (EE)"

значит, файл загружается. Прошёлся отладчиком, говорит, что символы для sfml-audio-d-2.dll не загружены

подскажите, это надо в свойствах проекта в Ввод > Дополнительные зависимости написать?

Нет, это говорит о том, что для библиотеки нет отладочных символов (.pdb файла). Если не собираетесь отлаживать код sfml, то оно и не нужно.

ну она всё равно не воспроизводится

@ArsenyVtor, а ваш файл точно в формате ogg? Или вы mp3 переименовали в ogg, хотя написано что mp3 декодирование поддерживается

Ну аудио файл теперь стал грузится. А с 0x88890004 надо смотреть баг репорты, типа этого https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/6742 Попробуйте обновить версию openAl и/или sfml.
